# Serverless not including my NodeJS dependencies

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I am facing uses using serverless to deploy an NodeJS on AWS. When I deploy the stack with `serverless deploy` it don't include all my dependencies that I declared on my packages.json

My serverless.yml

```
service: test-backend-auth-dev

frameworkVersion: ">=2.24.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline


custom:
  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      migrate: true
    # Comment if you don't have a DynamoDB running locally
      noStart: true
    migration:
      dir: offline/migrations
  logLevelMap:  
    prod: info
    staging: info
    dev: info
  logLevel: ${self:custom.logLevelMap.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}, 'debug'}

provider:
  name: aws
  region: eu-west-1
  stage: dev
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  logRetentionInDays: 30
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
    LOG_LEVEL: ${self:custom.logLevel}
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

functions:
  auth:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'

resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: email
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: email
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

An my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./node_modules/.bin/serverless offline start --noPrependStageInUrl",
    "migrate": "serverless dynamodb migrate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1193.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "dynamoose": "^2.8.6",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8",
    "serverless-http": "^3.0.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1193.0",
    "dynamoose": "^2.8.6",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "serverless-bundle": "^5.4.0",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.40",
    "serverless-offline": "^9.2.0",
    "serverless-plugin-include-dependencies": "^5.0.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.5",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",
    "winston": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

I don't understand why...
When I use `serverless package` and extract the zip file, I don't see all dependencies inside the node_modules directory like winston lib is missing.

```
serverless -v
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Framework Core: 3.21.0 (local) 3.21.0 (global)
Plugin: 6.2.2
SDK: 4.3.2
```

Using NodeJS v16.16.0

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've used in the past "[serverless-plugin-include-dependencies](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies)". That was the best solution I found. From Node16, on my own projects, it took several more time to run than it used to. It solved my problem of not having dependencies included.